# Are guest players taken into account when calculating scores in Mario Kart on WFC?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

In Mario Kart Wii, when you play online, after a race points are calculated based on the results of the race. Are guest racers taken into account in this calculation; in other words does it matter if a guest finishes before or after me? If so; how is his/her impact on the scores determined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Guests are taken into calculation online, they impact scores just like a normal player.

Me and my brother used to play MKWii online a lot, and when he finishes ahead of me, the points I get are calculated as-if a non-guest player finished ahead of me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In Worldwide/Continental races, guests are considered to have a VR/BR of 5000 for VR/BR calculations.

Source: http://wiki.tockdom.com/wiki/Player_Rating

Comment: Hi. This question was answered five years ago, and this answer is just repeating the same information. That's not very helpful, as it just creates noise.

Comment: @Wrigglenite True, but I added the actual VR/BR amount it accounts for, which was not included in the original answer. I thought this was useful information.

Comment: In the future you may want to consider just editing it into the existing answer, or providing a more fleshed out answer with sources

Comment: @Malco Ok. Thanks! I didn't change the original answer because I did not want to change the original author's meaning. I had heard this information in several places, but I was able to find a source for it. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @user9811991 With a question this old I wouldn't worry about upsetting the original answer-er, even for newer answers with more active users they will always have the option to tweak your edit (or reject it if they feel that strongly). As long as you are making a good attempt to improve the answer or add supporting information you shouldn't be worried about changing meaning. Also once you get a bit more Rep you will be able to leave comments if you wish.

Comment: @Malco Ok. I’ll keep that in mind for the future. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @user9811991No problem, glad to help. Thanks for contributing to the site and I hope you enjoy your time here :)